# Devextreme multiple selection List within a DropDownBox

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, multi-select, devextreme

I'm trying to build a multiple selection dropdown list with DevExtreme jQuery. I have looked at the demos on the DevExpress Web site, they use a TreeView or a Grid inside a DropDownBox. Adapting that code, here is what I wrote:

```
$('#list1').dxDropDownBox({
showClearButton: true,
valueExpr: 'Value',
displayExpr: 'Text',
dataSource: new DevExpress.data.ArrayStore({
    data: source,
    key: 'Value'
}),
contentTemplate: function (e) {
    var value = e.component.option("Value"),
        $list = $("<div>").dxList({
            dataSource: e.component.option("dataSource"),
            valueExpr: 'Value',
            displayExpr: 'Text',
            showSelectionControls: true,
            selectionMode: "all",
            selectedItemKeys: value,
            onSelectionChanged: function (e) {
                var selectedKeys = e.component.option("selectedItemKeys");
                e.component.option("Value", selectedKeys);
            }
        });

    return $list;
},
```

});

The source is an array of objects with two properties (Text and Value are the same here, but they can sometimes be different):

```
[{"Text":"2000","Value":"2000"},{"Text":"2005","Value":"2005"}]
```

The list shows as it should, but I have two issues:

- When I select one or more items in the list, the texts of the selected items are not displayed in the dropdown box (in the demos, it is displayed as a comma-separated text).
- I have put the list1 element in an HTML form (not a DevExtreme form), and I don't know how to post the selected values with the form (or even get them in jQuery).

Answer (score 1):

DevExtreme also has a [TagBox component](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/TagBox/Overview/jQuery/Light/) - it is a drop-down editor with List inside and an out of the box multiple selection. It will be a better solution.

If you still want to use a combination of DropDownBox and List, the issue is in

```
e.component.option("Value", selectedKeys);
```

DropDownBox doesn't have a *"Value"* option. You need to change the "[value](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/ApiReference/UI_Widgets/dxDropDownBox/Configuration/#value)" one instead:

```
e.component.option("value", selectedKeys);
```

You should use this option if you wish to get the component's value:

```
$('#list1').dxDropDownBox("instance").option("value");
```

See: [Widget Basics - Get and Set Options](https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Getting_Started/Widget_Basics_-_jQuery/Get_and_Set_Options/)

> Blockquote

Answer (score 0):

There is an additional problem with this code in that there is a variable clash with the variable 'e'. In the onSelectionChanged callback, the variable to the function should be changed to something other than 'e' to avoid name clashing with the definition of 'e' in the outer defintion of contentTemplate. Here is an example using 'arg' instead of 'e':

```
onSelectionChanged: function (arg) {
    var selectedKeys = arg.component.option("selectedItemKeys");
    e.component.option("value", selectedKeys);
}
```

That way 'arg' now refers to the selections in the checkbox list and then those items are correctly displayed in the parent control separated by commas.

Also, see a simple example on the DevExpress website at:
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Widgets/DropDownBox/Overview/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cust-select").dxDropDownBox({  
    value: [],  
    valueExpr: "Value",  
    placeholder: "-",  
    displayExpr: "Text",  
    showClearButton: true,  
    dataSource: JSON.parse($('#select-custvend').val()),  
    contentTemplate: function(e){  
        var value = e.component.option("value"),  
          $dataGrid = $("<div>").dxDataGrid({  
            dataSource: e.component.option("dataSource"),  
            columns: [{ dataField: "Text", caption: "Customer(s)" }],  
            hoverStateEnabled: true,  
            paging: { enabled: false },  
            filterRow: { visible: true },  
            scrolling: { mode: "infinite" },  
            height: 345,  
            selection: { mode: "multiple" },  
            selectedRowKeys: value,  
            onSelectionChanged: function(selectedItems){  
                var keys = selectedItems.selectedRowKeys;  
                e.component.option("value", keys);  
            },  
            width: "90%"  
          });  

        dataGrid = $dataGrid.dxDataGrid("instance");  

        e.component.on("valueChanged", function(args){  
            var value = args.value;  
            dataGrid.selectRows(value, false);  
        });  

        return $dataGrid;  
    }  
});
```

Comment: Please have a read of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) help page about how to format code properly.

Answer (score 0):

```
    url: '@Url.Action("GetTeam", "Team")',
    data: { dept: 0 },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#cbxTeam").dxDropDownBox({
            placeholder: @Json.Serialize(ViewData["Choose Team"].ToString()),
            displayExpr: name,
            showClearButton: true,
            dataSource: data,
            contentTemplate: function (e) {
                var value = e.component.option("value");

                $dataGrid = $("<div>").dxDataGrid({
                    dataSource: e.component.option("dataSource"),
                    columns: [name, 'g_ID'],
                    hoverStateEnabled: true,
                    paging: { enabled: true, pageSize: 10 },
                    filterRow: { visible: false },
                    showColumnHeaders: false,
                    scrolling: { mode: "infinite" },
                    height: 265,
                    selection: { mode: "multiple" },
                    selectedRowKeys: value,
                    onSelectionChanged: function (selectedItems) {
                        var keys = selectedItems.selectedRowKeys;
                        e.component.option("value", keys);
                    }
                });

                dataGrid = $dataGrid.dxDataGrid("instance");
                e.component.on("valueChanged", function (args) {
                    this.DefaultValueOne = args.value;
                    this.SelectedValues = args.value;
                    dataGrid.selectRows(args.value, false);

                   
                    txtTeam = "";
                    if (args.value != null) {
                        for (var i = 0; i < args.value.length; i++) {
                            if (i == args.value.length-1) {
                                txtTeam += args.value[i].g_ID;
                            } else {
                                txtTeam += args.value[i].g_ID + ",";
                            }
                            
                        }
                    }
                    //console.log(txtTeam);
                });

                return $dataGrid;
            }
```